# Select * is not showing records from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a query. It is not showing records from Mysql. I am trying to call data from Mysql so i can update it. But it is not fetching the data. Same code is working on other form and there Title is not showing too. Don't know whats wrong, but i have tried all things to show. 
Even tried to call the database connection file directly but still no success.

My PHP code

```
    <?php
if(isset($_GET['Competition_ID'])){

   $SelectAllPackages = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM competitions WHERE id='".$_GET['Competition_ID']."'");
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectAllPackages)){

    $competition_title      = $_POST['competition_title'];
    $vimeo_url              = $_POST['vimeo_url'];
    $start_date             = $_POST['start_date'];
    $end_date               = $_POST['end_date'];
    $tickets                = $_POST['tickets'];
    $ticket_price           = $_POST['ticket_price'];
    $status                 = $_POST['status'];
   }
}

if(isset($_POST['update_competition'])){


    $up_competition_title   = $_POST['competition_title'];
    $up_vimeo_url           = $_POST['vimeo_url'];
    $up_start_date          = $_POST['start_date'];
    $up_end_date            = $_POST['end_date'];
    $up_tickets             = $_POST['tickets'];
    $up_ticket_price        = $_POST['ticket_price'];
    $up_competition_status  = $_POST['status'];

    $insertQuery = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE competitions SET

    title                   = '$up_competition_title',
    vimeo_url               = '$up_vimeo_url',
    start_date              = '$up_start_date',
    end_date                = '$up_end_date',
    tickets                 = '$up_tickets',
    ticket_price            = '$up_ticket_price',
    status                  = '$up_competition_status'

    WHERE id='".$_GET['Competition_ID']."'
     "); 

    if($insertQuery){
        echo '<script>window.location.href = "all_competitions.php";</script>';
        }       
}


?>
```

My HTML code is here

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label">Competition Title</label>
                                                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="competition_title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: Are you tried echo the query directly with phpmyadmin?

Comment: There is an SQL Injection in $_GET['Competition_ID'], please use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: sorry didn't get you by echo the query directly with phpmyadmin

Comment: echo the sql query `select * `.The copy the query execute with phpmyadmin.Now you can get any error in sql query

Comment: any help please, where i am wrong?

Comment: Here i get when i run in phpmyadmin

SQL query: Documentation

$SelectAllPackages = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM competitions WHERE id='".$_GET['Competition_ID']."'")

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '$SelectAllPackages = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM competitions WHERE id='".' at line 1

Comment: did you include your `config` file ,how you are using `$con` then ? because i didn't saw that in your code.

Comment: Why do you write the data from your $_POST to the variables and not from $row?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use

```
if (isset($_POST['Competition_ID'])) {
  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Competition_ID']);
{
 if (empty($id)) {
    array_push($errors, "ID is required");
  }
if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM competition WHERE Competition_ID='$id'";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

Comment: thanks. i will take care of SQL injection, but yet i am struggling with data show.